# How can I remove checkboxes from lightning:treegrid

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

We have an application where we need checkbox to appear in only the top level record of tree-grid, and not the subsequent children.
Is there a flag or a nitpick to achieve the same ?
Currently I'm able to create a grid which looks something like this (with checkboxes in all the rows) :
[image: Current Design]

And we need to achieve the following (with checkbox appearing only in the parent row) :
[image: Expected Design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only flag to hide all checkboxes in first column: hideCheckboxColumn.
To achieve result simillar to what you described you can created your own tree grid component using Lightning Design System. Here is the link
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/#site-main-content